# Decyphering a string using a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has the key as the letters of the alphabet with values of numbers and hashtags depending on the number as so:

```
class Solution:
    def freqAlphabets(self, s: str) -> str:
        
        code_dict = {"a" : "1", "b": "2", "c" : "3", "d" : "4", "e" : "5", "f" : "6", "g" : "7", "h" : "8", "i" : "9", "j" : "10#", "k" : "11#", "l" : "12#", "m" : "13#", "n" : "14#", "o" : "15#", "p" : "16#", "q" : "17#", "r" : "18#", "s" : "19#", "t" : "20#", "u" : "21#", "v" : "22#", "w" : "23#", "x" : "24#", "y" : "25#", "z" : "26#"}
```

I want to decode a string into the subsequent work/letter depending on the value in the dictionary, for example: s = "10#11#12" would be "jkab" and s = "25#" would be "y".

I have the code below but the issue is, is that it will loop through the dictionary instead of read the string and look up what the value is. The issue I am having is that with my method when it comes across 1 it will count that as something in the string when it should just be 10# and then I get a 0 error as that is not in the dictionary. How would I go about implementing this instead?

```
    for key, value in code_dict.items():
        if value in s:
            print(code_dict[key])
```

Comment: I would loop over the string, the only issue is that a string could be 10# but it will instead look up values for 1, 0 and # when going over each character if that makes sense. I tried using indices by checking if the character is # and then checking for a string in the dictionary that is a merging of s[i-2] to s[i] but that didn't work either

Comment: why is some of the dictionary the other way round?
`"16#", "q" : "17#", "r" : "18#", "s" : "19#",` compared to for example
`"j" : "10#", "k" : "11#",`

Comment: splitting on # makes sense but what if I have the string 110#, it would split on # but does that also mean that it wouldn't be able to split 10# off like we want?

Comment: @JohnColeman spliting on "#" in the original example will give you `['10','11','12']` How will you know how to decode `12`

Comment: @MarkMeyer I misread OP's scheme as one in which `#` is a delimiter. Splitting on `#` could still work by slicing off the final two characters as one token and the rest of the characters in each component as single tokens.

Comment: @JohnColeman, I guess that's the point, the final two characters are two tokens: `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `code_dict` will be more useful if the key is the thing you actually want to look up (the encoded characters) -- in addition, you can generate it in a loop rather than having to type it all out, since it follows a simple pattern.

The tough part is tokenizing the input string, but you can take advantage of the fact that all of your tokens are **either** three characters and ending in `#` **or** single characters, which makes for a pretty simple state machine.

```
>>> def decode(msg: str) -> str:
...     code_dict = {
...         f'{n+1}{"#" if n > 8 else ""}': chr(ord('a') + n)
...         for n in range(26)
...     }
...     result = ""
...     while msg:
...         num_chars = 1 if len(msg) < 3 or msg[2] != "#" else 3
...         result += code_dict[msg[:num_chars]]
...         msg = msg[num_chars:]
...     return result
...
>>> decode("10#11#12")
'jkab'
>>> decode("25#")
'y'
```

Comment: Just to clarify does the while loop go until the string no longer exists?

Comment: The `while msg` means it goes until the string is "falsey", which in this case means empty.  The body of the loop progressively shrinks the string by reassigning it to be a smaller slice of itself (`msg = msg[num_chars:]` means "remove `num_chars` characters from the beginning of the string").